# ¿Cómo configurar GEMINI BLUEPRINT EN ECLIPSE?

Tags: java, spring

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una aplicación modular con spring usando GEMINI BLUEPRINT.
He seguido el tutorial oficial de GEMINI BLUEPRINT para configurar el contenedor de GEMINI BLUEPRINT; sin embargo los link de actualización de spring mencionados en el tutorial estan caidos, incluso he probado con los link actuales de actualizacion de spring no logrando pasar del "paso 1 del tutorial.

#
[gemini blueprint setup tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/3.0.0.M01/html-single/index.html#appendix-pde-integration)

#
[spring update site](https://web.archive.org/web/20070820215248/http://springide.org:80/updatesite_nightly/)

#
[current spring update site](http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.8/)